# mongoose update mutiple users array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have an array that has user's ids

array like this ["userid1","userid2","userid3"]

this array could have many user's id or just one. just random.

I'm just trying to update user's datas

if the array has 5 user's ids it's supposed to update 5 user's datas

here's what I did

```
  const { mentionUsers, sender, notificationType, image } = req.body;
  console.log(mentionUsers, sender, notificationType, image);
  try {
    if (mentionUsers.length === 0)
      return res.status(204).json({ message: "no mention users" });

    mentionUsers.map(async (userId) => {
      let notification = {
        _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
        sender,
        notificationType,
        image,
        read: false,
      };
      let user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(
        userId,
        { $push: { notifications: notification } },
        { new: true }
      );
      console.log(user);
    });
```

it doesn't update user's data

how can I update datas? thanks for reading my question

Comment: [`findByIdAndUpdate`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model-findByIdAndUpdate) just matches _one_ value, not an _array_ of values.  So to update multiple documents with different ids, you have to call just a regular `.update` and pass a filter document that matches any of the user ids using something like `$in`.  e.g.  `{ _id: $in: mentionUsers }` as Arman showed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update multiple documents at a time.

```
let notification = {
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    sender,
    notificationType,
    image,
    read: false
};

User.update(
    { _id: { $in: mentionUsers } },
    { $push: { notifications: notification } },
    { new: true }
);
```